# erorr formatting.php in word press

Tags: php, wordpress, formatting

My WordPress site gives this error in the comments section for products.
my erorr:
[erorr.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noQPy.png)

And its a complete error :
*Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home3/arsalear/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3410*

Error line photo in php file :
[eror line.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv5Az.png)

and :[this is the complete file](https://s17.picofile.com/file/8418904026/formatting.php.html)

Help me please....

Answer (score 0):

That's a warning and you can ignore them. I would recommend trying to fix the warning but adding the following to the affected webpage should remove the warning text.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING);
```